# Google maps API js errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typeerror

I have integrated Google maps using the API v3 and everything is working correctly however i am getting some console errors and wanted to see if anyone could point out why.

On Chrome i get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null VM262:13(anonymous function) VM262:13T.trigger main.js:15N.Hc VM261:137(anonymous function) main.js:13T.trigger main.js:15N.Xl VM261:122(anonymous function)

On firefox i get:
TypeError: s is null

Based on reading other answers it would appear that the dom hasn't fully loaded when the map is initialised but this does not seem to be the case as i'm running it on load. My code is below, if anyone could point me in the direction of why these errors might be occurring (everything seems to work correctly!) then that would be greatly appreciated (fyi there is some php code in here used to insert db variables into the js):

```
var map;
var infos = [];
var ib = new InfoBox();
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
    var contentString = '';
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'));
    var address = 'Netherlands';
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
       geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
          }
        });
    var markers = [
    [1, '52.350785','5.264702', 2, 'Almere', '01345'],[1, '52.992753','6.564228', 2, 'Assen', '012345678']
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        setMarkers(map, markers[i]);
    }
}

function setMarkers(map, beach) {
    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/img/marker.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
      new google.maps.Point(5, 34));

    var html = '<div class="phoney">'+beach[4]+'<br>'+beach[5]+'<\/div>';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach[1], beach[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    content:html,
    title: beach[4],
    zIndex: beach[3]
    });

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "border: 2px solid #4a5461; margin-top: 8px;background: #ffffff; padding: 5px;font-family: \'ff-din-web-n6\',\'ff-din-web\',sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color: #4a5461;";
    boxText.innerHTML = beach[4] + '<br>' + beach[5];

    var myOptions = {
    content:boxText,
    disableAutoPan: false,
    maxWidth: 0,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    boxStyle: {
        width: "200px"
    },
    closeBoxMargin: "13px 5px 2px 2px",
    closeBoxURL: "/img/close.png",
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1),
    isHidden: false,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
    ib.setOptions(myOptions);
    ib.open(map, marker);
    });
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Thanks very much,

Dave

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (we don't know what the data in your database is; or have your HTML/CSS)

Comment: I have removed the PHP and hardcoded the variables. For the HTML there is just a div with id=map-canvas. Thanks very much

Comment: I don't see any javascript errors ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mak5unj/)), did you confirm they happen with the example you posted?  Not the issue, but google.maps.MarkerImage is deprecated, replaced with the google.maps.Icon anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

Make sure that lat, long are decimal values as such:

var center = { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 };